# Coreutils : "error: automatic de-ANSI-fication support has been removed"

Tags: linux, gnu-coreutils

I am trying to compile [coreutils](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils) in my local but I am facing the following error:

```
...
./bootstrap: m4/wchar_t.m4 overrides ._bootmp2/m4/wchar_t.m4
./bootstrap: m4/wint_t.m4 overrides ._bootmp2/m4/wint_t.m4
./bootstrap: m4/xsize.m4 overrides ._bootmp2/m4/xsize.m4
./bootstrap: aclocal --force -I m4  ...
configure.ac:46: error: automatic de-ANSI-fication support has been removed
/usr/share/aclocal-1.16/obsolete.m4:26: AM_C_PROTOTYPES is expanded from...
m4/jm-macros.m4:188: gl_CHECK_ALL_TYPES is expanded from...
m4/jm-macros.m4:22: coreutils_MACROS is expanded from...
configure.ac:46: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
```

Anyone that could point me into the right direction?

Thanks a lot in advance :-)